# React Native - Linked Library works in Xcode, but not when run w/ Packager

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I recently added `react-native-vector-icons` to my project and followed the instruction on [Linking Libraries](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#content)

When I run w/ Xcode, everything works, but when I run w/ packager, I get the following error...

[image]

Everything looks as it should per the documentation as shown in the screenshots below?

[image]

[image]

The only thing I can think of that was done differently in Xcode was I set the deployment target to 9.3.

Any ideas on why it would be working in one and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

After running into the same problem, I found that `react-native run-ios` seems not to include linked libraries when I configured different `Product Name`s for `Debug` and `Release` in my project's `Build Settings`. XCode builds continued to work just fine:

[image: single product name]

versus

[image: different product names]